# Асинхронность в python

Tags: python, asyncio, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Имеется REST API, реализованный на FASTApi:

```
@app.get('/api/all_transfers', response_model=List[TransferOut])
async def all_transfers(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    transfer_data = await get_all_transfers(db)
    return transfer_data
```

Функция get_all_transfers(db)

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from repository.DatabaseConnection import SessionLocal
from repository.models import Transfers

import asyncio

async def get_all_transfers(db: Session):
    all_transfers = db.query(Transfers).all()
    if all_transfers:
        return all_transfers
    else:
        return {"error": "error text"}
```

отправляю запросы в БД для получения данных из test.py:

```
import requests
from threading import Thread
import json
import time


def send_request():
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/all_transfers"
    for i in range(50):
        response = requests.get(url)
        print(response.text)
        print('good')
    else:
        print('bad')

thread1 = Thread(target=send_request)

start = time.time()
thread1.start()
thread1.join()
end = time.time() - start
print('Time :', end)
```

В какой-то момент отправка запросов останавливается. Мои подозрения:  неправильно реализованная асинхронность. Почему моя асинхронность не работает?

UPD: Подключение к БД

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, Session

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:934007717@localhost:5432/megafon")

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
```

Comment: Отправка останавливается или сервис перестает отвечать? По-хорошему имеет смысл делать `response.raise_for_status()` после запроса, чтобы видеть, что сервис не 200 ОК стал отвечать. Во-вторых, вы не асинхронную сессию используете, запросы к базе будут выполняться строго синхронно. Посмотрите примеры с AsyncSession.

Comment: В коде отправки не понятно зачем в поток обернуто, у вас в итоге параллельно с этим потоком ничего не выполняется.

Comment: Когда идёт отправка запросов в потоке, в консоли где я слежу за сервером uvicorn не отображаются новые запросы, следовательно я предположил, что запросы просто выполняются. Возможно обрабатываются, возможно залагало. Но в uvicorn не появляются новые данные. В потоки я завернул, да моя ошибка, прошу прощения, я должен был исправленный код отправить, где отправляются два потока обращения к бд.

Comment: Ну тут имеет смысл добавить и при отправке например принты при начале отправки и при получении ответа (не забывая про обработку не ОК статусов), так и на сервере например логирование прихода запроса.

Comment: Ну и сессию на асинхронную поменять. А то от того что вы async к методу дописали не делает автоматически сам код внутри него асинхронным.

Comment: Переходит ли моя синхронность в асинхронность если при подключении к БД я буду использовать postgresql+asyncpg? До этого было postgresql + psycopg2. Я обновил вопрос - добавил код с подключением к бд.

Comment: Если напрямую работать с asyncpg, то будет асинхронно. Чтобы через алхимию асинхронно работать, нужно асинхронные сессии использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Во первых обращение в БД у тебя не асинхронное. Тебе нужно использовать [`AsyncSession`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html), чтобы с помощью `sqlalchemy` делать не блокирующие запросы.

Простое добавление `async` перед `def` не делает функцию сразу асинхронной.

Твоя функция должна быть примерно такой:

```
async def get_all_transfers(db: AsyncSession):
    async with db.begin():
         all_transfers = (await db.execute(select(Transfers))).scalars()
    return all_transfers
```

А вызов этой функции:

```
@app.get('/api/all_transfers', response_model=List[TransferOut])
async def all_transfers():
    async with async_session() as session:
        transfer_data = await get_all_transfers(db)
    return transfer_data
```

В целом почитай документацию про то как использовать [sqlachemy в asyncio](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html) и чтобы лучше понять как работает асинхронный код можно почитать статью про [генераторы и asyncio](https://go-coding.dev/article/Delaem-svoi-asyncio-na-osnove-Python-generatorov-Chtoby-poniat-kak-ustroeny-asyncio-i-korutiny).